# only keep Group in df1 which are present in another df with exception

Tags: r

In order to only keep Group in df1 which are present in Group of df2 I use:

```
restricted_df<-df1[df1$Group %in% df2$Group,]
```

But how to do the same thing but `%in% df2$Group` where `df2$col2 contain a point`.` ?

Here is an example

df1

```
Group col2
A AZ
A AP
A EZ
B EA
B RT
C ES
D TR
E GT
```

df2

```
Group Col2
A ok.l
C ok
E ok.po
```

restricted_df

```
Group col2
A AZ
A AP
A EZ
E GT
```

Answer (score 0):

Subset only those groups from `df2` which has `'ok'` :

```
df1[df1$Group %in% df2$Group[grepl('\\.', df2$Col2)],]

#  Group col2
#1     A   AZ
#2     A   AP
#3     A   EZ
#8     E   GT
```

Or using joins with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  filter(grepl('\\.', Col2)) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'Group') %>%
  select(-Col2)
```

Comment: How and what if I do not want it to be == exaclty to something but instead contain a pattern such as a '.' ? I edited the exemple

Answer (score 0):

Here, is an option using `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %%>%
  filter(str_detect(Col2, "\\.")) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'Group') %>%
  select(-Col2)
```